# Compute Jordan normal form of matrix in Python / NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

In MATLAB you can compute the Jordan normal form of a matrix by using the the function `jordan`.

It there an equivalent function available in NumPy and SciPy?

Comment: In sage, you are looking for jordan_form, see [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix2.html#sage.matrix.matrix2.Matrix.jordan_form). This is not scipy/numpy though.

Comment: Just a comment: Jordan form computation is numerically unstable in floating point --- you can e.g. try to compute the eigenvalues of the 4x4 matrix [in sympy jordan_form docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.Matrix.jordan_form). LAPACK (and therefore Scipy) will report that it has 4 distinct eigenvalues. Exact arithmetic gives however a 4-fold degenerate eigenvalue of 2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The MATLAB [jordan function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jordan.html) is from the Symbolic Math Toolbox, so it does not seem unreasonable to get its Python replacement from the [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) library.  Specifically, the `Matrix` class has the method `jordan_form`.  You can pass a numpy array as an argument when you create a sympy Matrix.  For example, the following is from the [wikipedia article on the Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from sympy import Matrix

In [3]: a = np.array([[5, 4, 2, 1], [0, 1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 3, 0], [1, 1, -1, 2]])

In [4]: m = Matrix(a)

In [5]: m
Out[5]: 
Matrix([
[ 5,  4,  2,  1],
[ 0,  1, -1, -1],
[-1, -1,  3,  0],
[ 1,  1, -1,  2]])

In [6]: P, J = m.jordan_form()

In [7]: J
Out[7]: 
Matrix([
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 4, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 4]])
```

Comment: Just a comment: Jordan form computation is numerically unstable in floating point --- you can e.g. try to compute the eigenvalues of the 4x4 matrix [in sympy jordan_form docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.Matrix.jordan_form). LAPACK (and therefore Scipy) will report that it has 4 distinct eigenvalues. Exact arithmetic gives however a 4-fold degenerate eigenvalue of 2.

Answer (score -4):

There's [this](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/python-gaussj/) implementation.

It will definitely not be as fast as MATLAB, though.

Comment: That transforms the matrix into reduced row echolon form, which can be done more efficienty with sympy.Matrix(...).rref()

However, I'm looking for the jordan normal form:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form