# Compute Jordan normal form for big matrices in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, bigdata

Hi

I want to compute Jordan normal form of big circular matrix in Matlab(i.e order of  365 x 365)

for an example a 4x4 circular matrix has the form :

`A = [0 1 0 0 ; 0 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0 1 ;1 0 0 0]`

When I call it for AA with dimention of 365 x 365:

`[v,j] = eng.jordan(mtdb_G_time_cyc,nargout = 2)`

I get this error :

```
Error using symengine (line 58)
Similarity matrix is too large.

Error in sym/mupadmexnout (line 875)
    out = mupadmex(fcn,args{:});

Error in sym/jordan (line 34)
    [Vsym,Jsym] = mupadmexnout('symobj::jordan',A,'All');

Error in double/jordan (line 25)
[V,J] = jordan(sym(A));

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/MSC/Term1/BD/Paper_persentation/Code/big data GSP/main.py", line 
79, in <module>
[v,j] = eng.jordan(mtdb_G_time_cyc,nargout = 2)
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\matlab\engine\matlabengine.py", line 80, in __call__
_stderr).result()
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\matlab\engine\futureresult.py", line 109, in result
self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
matlab.engine.MatlabExecutionError: 
File C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\symengine.p, 
line 58, in symengine

File C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\sym.m, 
line 875, in sym.mupadmexnout

 File C:\Program 
 Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\jordan.m, line 34, in 
 jordan

 File C:\Program 
 Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@double\jordan.m, line 25, in 
 jordan
 Similarity matrix is too large.
```

Actually, I call Matlab function through the python.

Is there any way which I can compute Jordan form ?

I would appreciate your solutions

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the Matlab implementation is symbolic. So I doubt that there is much you can do.

Comment: For what its worth, the reason that Matlab probably doesnt have a non-symbolic version is that the Jordan decomposition is numerically unstable. The reason this is the case is that multiplicity is a very discontinuous operation. If I change the input matrix by some very small value, all of a sudden, one of the roots might have a multiplicity, meaning that one of the entries should switch from a 0 to a 1. From a numerical point of view, that means that I perturb the matrix by an infinitely small value, and the output should change by 1... That is a huge numerical problem.

Comment: Why do you need to compute it through MATLAB? Did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20381005/3372061) using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. But the problem exist as well